# Adding elements to the page without re-rendering already added elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large array of objects, one object - one element. I use `map ()` to render them on the page, but only the first 5. I have a button "show 5 more", when I click on it, 5 more are rendered and in total already 10.

The problem is that when rendering 5 more elements, the rest are re-rendered, which is bad for performance. I'm using functional components so `shouldComponentUpdate ()` won't work. `react-window` won't do either, since I don't have a huge scroll. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your functional component in `React.memo(...)`. If the inputs (properties) are the same, React will cache the output and skip re-rendering.